# Visual C++ application opens a command prompt behind the form

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I created a empty CLR project in Visual Studio 2017 and added Windows Forms.
After starting the app there opens a command prompt and my form application. Is there any way to diable the command prompt? [Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0CtL.png)

Comment: Change the setting to 'GUI App'  instead of 'Console App' in the Project settings.

Comment: @zx485 I tryed to look in every bullet in the properties tab but there is no point that says anything about GUI App or Console App. Maybe I am looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Finaly I got the forms working correctly with just seting the entry point to main and the SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). Also I added some lines to the MyForm.cpp. Now it looks like

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;


[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm mainForm;
    Application::Run(%mainForm);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to:
@ AntonMalyshev 
and 
@zx485

Answer (score 3):

You need to change running subsystem from Console to GUI in project's properties (see the image attached).

Also don't forget to use `int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` as your main function.

[image: settings]

Comment: I canged the subsystem to windows because tere is no GUI option and it gave me an error also I do not understand what does "Also don't forget to use int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow); as your main function." means. Sorry for my stupidness I am new in this.

Comment: It is the function called in Windows subsystem instead of `int main`

Comment: What does this mean? Should I put it istead the int main functin or should I put it as an entry point?

Comment: Both :) you don't need main and you need to choose wWinMain as entry point

Comment: I putted as an entry point in the Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point wWinMain and setted the Linker -> System -> SubSystem to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS). Than I comented my int main() and added the `int WINAPI (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` in the MyForm.cpp and I got multiple errors. The moust part on them are that the syntax of wWinMain is wrong in the line where the int WINAPI ... is.

Comment: Now I am a little confused. 0_o

Comment: try adding `#include "windows.h"` in the beginning of the file with wWinMain, also probably it's better to use more general variant of main function: `int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` which should work with wide char as well as with ansi char

Comment: I used 'int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)' as tha main function. Also I tried to change the entry point to _tWinMain and wWinMain and now I have a new type of error. I added 'windows.h' and now there are only two errors that appear: 'Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1287 invalid managed entry point "int __stdcall _tWinMain(struct HINSTANCE__ *,struct HINSTANCE__ *,wchar_t *,int)" (?_tWinMain@@$$FYGHPAUHINSTANCE__@@0PA_WH@Z) 1' this comed when I used an an entry point _tWinMain.

Comment: The second error looks like `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _wWinMain Project1` when I use as an enry point wWinMain. I do not see any logic in this stuff. Why does the same versions of visual studio works diffrently on two PCs? I mean why is the visual C++ so unstable?

Comment: please update the full answer, which you described very well in comments. thanks.